# How to handle this JsonRpcProvider error?

Tags: reactjs, web3js, metamask, ethers.js

```
// const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider();
```

I have this error in this line of code this code

> (Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ])

I don't know what to put in the brackets to avoid the error
I'm integrating React(Create-react-app) + Metamask, now I only can connect the wallet to localhost:3000

I need to read this contract (https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x0bdad987f8a762ae61fe07592fb8bdd1b2f6937c#code)
and fetch userCount variable from there to my app, but now I can only get this error: call revert exception.

I've also tried this:
`const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)`
But it didn't help either.

```
  const [usageOnCount, setUsageOnCount] = useState(null)

  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider();
  // const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, provider)

  const main = async () => {
    const usageCount = await contract.usageCount()
    setUsageOnCount(usageCount)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    main()
  }, [usageOnCount])
```

Comment: You have to add the URL to which you're connecting it. If that doesn't work, what does provider.connection() return?